# I Want to Get the See More Post After 6 post on custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php $series = get_field('movies'); ?>

<?php foreach($series as $series):?>

            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($series->ID);?>"> <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($series->ID, 'thumbnail');?>"></a>

            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($series->ID);?>"><h3><?php echo $series->post_title;?></h3></a>

            <?php the_field( 'movies_details', $series->ID );?>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

guys im newbee in web development please help me thats my code i want to see more post on custom post type

Comment: How many posts do you have in total?

Comment: more than 10 why?